# Spring dataSource bean definition failing

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, datasource

I'm trying to use Spring's JdbcTemplate to simplify my DAOs in a Java web service that is deployed in Tomcat and connects to Postgres.

I'm following [Spring's documention](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html), and I'm trying configure a DataSource in the application context file, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.manta" />

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
  </bean>

  <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/db.properties"/>

</beans>
```

I have the following `db.properties` file in the appropriate place:

```
driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver 
url=jdbc:postgresql://pgprod.ecnext.com:5432/manta
username=my_user_name
password=my_password
```

When I try to deploy, I find the following stack trace in `catalina.out`:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context.xml]: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'driverClassName'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:656)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Things that are NOT the problem:

1. The `db.properties` file is in the correct location.
2. The credentials in the `db.properties` are correct, and can be read in manually to connect to the database.
3. The `context.xml` file is being found by the ContextLoaderListener, and I am able to inject other dependencies.

I would very much appreciate any suggestions as to what could cause this. I'm using Spring 3.1.1, and Tomcat 7.0.26.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have multiple `<context:property-placeholder ... >` in your project which each create a new instance of the underlying object, and is a doorway to pains...

I prefer using the following declaration for loading property files:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"     class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:db-config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

Drop the leading slash from your location (i.e. `location="WEB-INF/db.properties"` ) or better yet change it to classpath:

```
location="classpath:db.properties"
```

Comment: `classpath:db.properties` worked for me. Any chance you could explain the difference? It seemed (from the log files) that it was finding the file before.

Comment: It turns out that this helped me because I had made a copy of db.properties and was editing the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

`use org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`
instead of `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

Use **ignore-unresolvable="true"** in you application context. Default value is 'fales' you need to set it 'true' so pass on the key to any others in the context that have not yet visited.

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="/WEB-INF/application.properties" />
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="/WEB-INF/dbcp.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the maven dependency properly, Sping-core and Spring-context dependencies should be present in your project.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version></version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version></version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Don't think that was the problem, but will never know. This question is three years old.