# Error while running my maven project using springmvc and hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'hibernate.show_sql'
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:272)
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:640)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:405)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:501)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

spring-config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">    
    <context:component-scan  base-package="controller" />  
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
    </bean>  

   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties"/>
</bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />  
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />  
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />  
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />  
    </bean>  

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
        <property name="annotatedClasses">    
            <list>    
                <value>com.model.Emp</value>    
            </list>    
        </property>   
        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">  
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="dataDaoImpl" class="com.dao.DataDaoImpl" />  

</beans>
```

Comment: You're not providing a value for the `hibernate.show_sql` variable from outside the application (config, command-line parameters, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property placeholder in the spring-config.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />
```

and your variable ${hibernate.show_sql} should be defined in foo.properties. Or you can add it to your existing property file : database.properties

more info at http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

The cause this error is the Spring can't change the connection properties names alias.

```
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />  
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />  
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />  
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
```

If you can. Specify the information in this file for test.
specify password, user... directly in the xml file.

The same version your Spring. See this:

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

The similar problem here: 
[Spring dataSource bean definition failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450240/spring-datasource-bean-definition-failing)

verify your java class contain the configuration.
Similar this:

[spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and context:property-placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542506/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-and-contextproperty-placeholder)